# how to upload multiple images using multi_image_picker: ^4.6.7 and Dio in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a new to flutter, I have been facing a problem while uploading images to the server using `multi_image_picker` and `dio`.

I've been successful in obtaining multiple images using the `multi_image_picker` but failed to upload the images to server.

please help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:multi_image_picker/multi_image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
  String _error = 'No Error Dectected';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget buildGridView() {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
        Asset asset = images[index];
        return AssetThumb(
          asset: asset,
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  Future<void> loadAssets() async {
    List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();
    String error = 'No Error Dectected';

    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 300,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets: images,
        cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
          actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
          actionBarTitle: "Example App",
          allViewTitle: "All Photos",
          useDetailsView: false,
          selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
        ),
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      error = e.toString();
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      images = resultList;
      _error = error;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(child: Text('Error: $_error')),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Pick images"),
              onPressed: loadAssets,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: buildGridView(),
            )
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.file_upload),
          onPressed: () {
            print(images);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Only need to create the Multipart object of each image.

You can get the byte array from the Assets

```
 ByteData byteData = await asset.getByteData();
  List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
```

then it can pass through **MultipartFile.fromBytes()** method.

so it will look like,

```
  String url = "upload/url";

          List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
          List<MultipartFile> multipartImageList = new List<MultipartFile>();
          if (null != images) {
            for (Asset asset in images) {
              ByteData byteData = await asset.getByteData();
              List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
              MultipartFile multipartFile = new MultipartFile.fromBytes(
                imageData,
                filename: 'load_image',
                contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg"),
              );
              multipartImageList.add(multipartFile);
            }

            FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
              "multipartFiles": multipartImageList,
              "userId": '1'
            });

            Dio dio = new Dio();
            var response = await dio.post(url, data: formData);
          }
```

[FYI](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/330)

Answer (score 2):

**Use [multi_image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker) class. How to upload image file using restAPI in flutter/dart**

```
// string to uri
Uri uri = Uri.parse('enter api url here');

// create multipart request
MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

ByteData byteData = await asset.getByteData();
List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

MultipartFile multipartFile = MultipartFile.fromBytes(
 'photo',  //key of the api
 imageData,
 filename: 'some-file-name.jpg',
 contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg"), //this is not nessessory variable. if this getting error, erase the line.
);

// add file to multipart
request.files.add(multipartFile);
// send
var response = await request.send();
```

name spaces

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/http.dart';
```

Comment: good for adding one image, but now multiple as the question stated?